# How can Sonic fly using Tails?

Tags: sonic-3, sonic-3-and-knuckles

I have seen videos where Tails grabs Sonic and is able to fly carrying him. I have tried several key combinations but am unable to get it to work. How can I do this?

This is what it looks like, although it can be done besides this boss battle:

[image]

Comment: My memory is quite hazy, so I'm quite possibly wrong.  I seem to remember, though, that this was only possible when playing with two players, where the second player is controlling Tails

Comment: Playing as Tails also has other advantages: http://www.dorkly.com/video/22718/dorkly-bits-tails-cant-die

Comment: This question can also apply to Sonic Mania, as the answer  is the same for both games.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can only do this if you are playing in Sonic & Tails mode. You need to at least have a second controller if you're playing by yourself. You need to make Tails fly by having him jump in the air, then hit the jump button again in mid-air. He'll then start flying and you need to keep hitting the jump button to make him ascend or release it to descend. After about 8 seconds on the ingame clock, he'll descend to the ground again because he's "tired." You can also kill enemies if you hit them with your tails.

While he's in the air, you can either have him fly over Sonic to pick him up or have Sonic jump up to grab his hands. Tails will move slower because of Sonic's weight. Note you can also do this underwater, as Tails can "swim" then, but you can't ascend while hanging onto Sonic.

Comment: Probably goes without saying, but this also works in Sonic 3 & Knuckles.

Comment: For swimming have sonic keep jumping, just don't miss catching him!

Comment: I can confirm this method also works in Sonic Mania.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible if you have a second player who is controlling Tails. They can then pick Sonic up and you can fly.

Comment: -1.  One skilled player holding two controllers at once can use Tails to pick Sonic up.  See [FAE's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/39721/37055).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one player, opting to play both characters simultaneously. On a smartphone/tablet/touchscreen device, just slide the button on the left up while repeatedly tapping the button on the right. This activates flying Tails. If you do it while he and Sonic are adjacent to each other, Tails will just swoop Sonic up. Otherwise, once Tails is airborne, have Sonic jump up to grab his hands.

Comment: This is how it worked in the mobile ports, but note that Sonic 3 does not have a mobile port.

Answer (score -1):

Tails can fly in Sonic 2 during singleplayer. I think you have to get that one power up that has the mini stars circling around you, then you jump up and in the air, afterwards you press jump again and you should fly but you must keep pressing jump to keep going. But another perspective is you must beat the game using tails

Comment: Here's a suggestion, if the answer isn't very clear or its just a "I think" it would probably fit better in the comments section. Also, I do not understand what you mean from the last sentence. Try not to make your answer like an informal text message. Answers are more accepted when you are clear and professional in your writing.

Answer (score -3):

You have to look up using sonic then jump but keep in mind tails has to be right behind you

Comment: So wait, are you saying its possible with one controller? If so, can you provide proof?

Comment: This is how it worked in the mobile ports, but note that Sonic 3 does not have a mobile port.

Comment: I believe this worked in Sonic or Sonic 2; but I don't know if I've played 3.